# When can we use Differentiation under the Integral sign?

Tags: integration, soft-question

Let me elaborate, 'Feynman's' trick ranks up in the top ten on most people's list, right behind contour integration, for best ways to evaluate definite integrals.

However, unlike [contour integration](http://www.solitaryroad.com/c614.html) , this method doesn't really seem to have a users manual on how and when to use the method. In addition I rarely see the trick used on this site, and even when I do, it's usually in conjunction with contour integration or some other trick, so it makes it hard to see exactly what property is being exploited.

Are there certain classes of integrals where using this method makes sense? In general, when is it best to use Feynman's trick?

Here are my own thoughts. $e^{p \cdot x}$ is an important kernel used in the Laplace transform. In addition, it's derivative with respect to $p$ adds an $x$ term to the integral increasing the likelihood that a trick like integration by parts would work. Thus, functions with Laplace transforms might be solvable using Feynman Integration.

Comment: See [this PDF](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-304-undergraduate-seminar-in-discrete-mathematics-spring-2006/projects/integratnfeynman.pdf)

Comment: @user170231 I know what the technique is. I want the overarching class of definite integrals evaluable by this technique. The PDF only gives a list of examples, useful, but not what I wanted.

Comment: The second page lists the conditions required in order to interchange the anti/differentiation operators.

Comment: @user170231: I am not completely sure, but I think the question asks more about "fuzzy" criteria for recognizing when differentiation under the integral sign **may be worthwile** (i.e. simplify things), than formal criteria when it is justified.

Comment: @user170231 Exactly what PeomueX said.

Comment: @PhoemueX the conditions need not be fuzzy, but could be. The link I provide shows specific instances were classes of integrals can done with contour integration.

Comment: Often you want to get rid of a logarithm or some of his descendants like arctan. Then differentation w.r.t. a parameter is very useful because you can trade in an irrational function for a rational one.